# Query Performance Issue in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, query-optimization

I tried a query to fetch data from db but when I use add the following subqueries then it takes a lot of time, It fetches all the data from db then again uses subquery to fetch further data from memory.

I also tried to join with response table to fetch only required data but that still didn't solve the performance issue.

Here are the lines which causes performance issue:

```cs
projectType= internshipNameResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 22).Answer,
additionalCriteria = internshipNameResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 27).Answer,
tamidStudent = internshipNameResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 28).Answer,
studentEmail = internshipNameResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 2134).Answer,
jobDesc = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 17).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
experience = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 21).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
VCF = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 4239).Select(x => x.AnswerCode).ToList(),
lang = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 23).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
codingLang = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 24).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
academic = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 25).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
HPD = internshipNameResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 26).Answer,
```

Here is the complete Query:

```cs
var result = (from cr in CompanyRepresentatives.Where(x=> companyIds.Contains(x.ID) )
    join p in QuestionnaireResponses on cr.ID equals p.RespondentID
    join q in Responses on p.ID equals q.QuestionnaireResponseID into internshipNameResponses
    join x in Responses on p.ID equals x.QuestionnaireResponseID into posibleAnswerResponses
    from internshipNameRes in internshipNameResponses
    from possibleAnsRes in posibleAnswerResponses
    where internshipNameRes.QuestionID == 2130 &&
        possibleAnsRes.QuestionID == 29 &&
        p.QuestionnaireID == 2 &&
          
        cr.Active == true &&

          //Applying the name filter
          (string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyOrInternshipName) || cr.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(companyOrInternshipName) ||
          (internshipNameRes != null && internshipNameRes.Answer.ToLower().Contains(companyOrInternshipName))) &&

          //Applying the status filter
          

          //Applying the year filter
          
          //applying the active filter
          (includeHidden || !p.IsHidden)
    orderby cr.CompanyName
    select new 
    {
        ID = p.ID,
        Name = internshipNameRes.Answer,
        CompanyID = cr.ID,
        Company = cr.CompanyName,
        CompanyEmail = cr.Email,
        CompanyDesc = cr.CompanyDescription,
        usOfficeCity = cr.USOffice_City,
        isrOfficeoth = cr.IsraelOffice_City_Other,
        CompanyRank = cr.Rank,
        projectType= internshipNameResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 22).Answer,
        additionalCriteria = internshipNameResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 27).Answer,
        tamidStudent = internshipNameResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 28).Answer,
        studentEmail = internshipNameResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 2134).Answer,
        AvailablePositions = possibleAnsRes.Answer,
        FilledPositions = p.FilledVacancies,
        Status = p.Status,
        Visible = !p.IsHidden,
        DatePosted = p.Created,
        Rejected = p.IsInternshipRejected,
        jobDesc = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 17).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
        experience = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 21).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
        VCF = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 4239).Select(x => x.AnswerCode).ToList(),
        lang = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 23).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
        codingLang = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 24).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
        academic = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 25).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
        HPD = internshipNameResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 26).Answer,
        industry = cr.CompanyIndustry,
        companySize = cr.CompanySize,
        usOffice = cr.USOffice_City,
        isrOffice = cr.IsraelOffice_City,
        companyType = cr.CompanyType,
        market = cr.CompanyTargetMarket,
        financingStage = cr.FinancingStage
    }).ToList();
```

Here is the first version of Query:

```
(from p in se.QuestionnaireResponses
                                          join q in se.Responses on p.ID equals q.QuestionnaireResponseID
                                          join x in se.Responses on p.ID equals x.QuestionnaireResponseID
                                          where q.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.INTERNSHIP_NAME_QUESTION_ID &&
                                          x.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.AVAILABLE_POS_QUESTION_ID &&
                                          p.QuestionnaireID == SurveyEntities.COMPANY_INTERNSHIP_QUESTIONNAIRE_ID &&
                                          companyIds.Contains(p.CompanyRepresentative.ID) &&
                                          p.CompanyRepresentative.Active &&

                                           //Applying the name filter
                                           (string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyOrInternshipName) || p.CompanyRepresentative.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(companyOrInternshipName) ||
                                           (q != null && q.Answer.ToLower().Contains(companyOrInternshipName))) &&

                                           //Applying the status filter
                                           (status.Equals("all") || p.Status.Equals(status)) &&

                                           //Applying the year filter
                                           DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.Created).Value, new DateTime(startYear, 6, 16)) >= 0 &&
                                           DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.Created).Value, new DateTime(endYear, 6, 15)) <= 0 &&

                                           //applying the active filter
                                           (includeHidden || !p.IsHidden)
                                          orderby p.CompanyRepresentative.CompanyName
                                          select new InternshipVM
                                          {
                                              ID = p.ID,
                                              Name = q.Answer,
                                              CompanyID = p.CompanyRepresentative.ID,
                                              Company = p.CompanyRepresentative.CompanyName,
                                              CompanyEmail = p.CompanyRepresentative.Email,
                                              CompanyDesc = p.CompanyRepresentative.CompanyDescription,
                                              usOfficeCity = p.CompanyRepresentative.USOffice_City,
                                              isrOfficeoth = p.CompanyRepresentative.IsraelOffice_City_Other,
                                              CompanyRank = p.CompanyRepresentative.Rank,
                                              projectType= p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.INTERNSHIP_PROJECT_TYPES_QUESTION_ID).Answer,
                                              additionalCriteria = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.ADDITIONAL_CRITERIA).Answer,
                                              tamidStudent = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.ALREADY_SELECTED_TAMID_STUDENT).Answer,
                                              studentEmail = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.ADDITIONAL_EMAIL_ADDRESSES).Answer,
                                              AvailablePositions = x.Answer,
                                              FilledPositions = p.FilledVacancies,
                                              Status = p.Status,
                                              Visible = !p.IsHidden,
                                              DatePosted = p.Created,
                                              Rejected = p.IsInternshipRejected,
                                              jobDesc = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.JOB_DESCRIPTIONS).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
                                              experience = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.TYPE_OF_EXPERIENCE).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
                                              VCF = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.SUPPLEMENTAL_INDUSTRY).Select(x => x.AnswerCode).ToList(),
                                              lang = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.PREFERRED_LANGUAGES).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
                                              codingLang = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.PREFERRED_CODING_LANGUAGES).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
                                              academic = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.ACADEMIC_BACKGROUND).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
                                              HPD = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == InternshipViewModel.WORKING_HOURS).Answer,
                                              industry = p.CompanyRepresentative.CompanyIndustry,
                                              companySize = p.CompanyRepresentative.CompanySize,
                                              usOffice = p.CompanyRepresentative.USOffice_City,
                                              isrOffice = p.CompanyRepresentative.IsraelOffice_City,
                                              companyType = p.CompanyRepresentative.CompanyType,
                                              market = p.CompanyRepresentative.CompanyTargetMarket,
                                              financingStage = p.CompanyRepresentative.FinancingStage
                                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: your multiple filter iterate the whole collection many times.  your main filter is on `QuestionID` so you should start by doing a `var questionGrouped = internshipNameResponses.GroupBy(o=> o.QuestionID);` and then simply get the correct one like `var studentEmail  = questionGrouped.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.Key == 2134)[0].Answer;` or something like that. This would cut iteration by 11 times

Comment: Which ORM do you use? Which version? EF Core would not translate such query.  GroupJoin has very limited usage.

Comment: @TimSchmelter without ToList is the same and total records it returns is 1369

Comment: @Franckcan you please let me know where the code should be injected as I did on the top to get all the matched responses but still takes a lot of time.

Comment: @Franck can you please suggest where to add the code?

Comment: @EngrUmair that should be right before your first code block in the post where you go grab specific question id.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest not using `FirstOrDefault` (which returns `null` in this case, if nothing matches), as you are not handling the `null` value here. Instead use the function `First`, which will give you a better error description.

You could step through the code and see exactly, which line is causing the problem (it tells you the time after each line).
As you go through the table `internshipNameResponses` very often, I would suggest going over it only once and filtering it, then use the filtered table:

```
var questionIDs = new []{17, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 2134, 4239};
var filteredResponses = internshipNameResponses.Where(y => questionIDs.Contains(y.QuestionID)).ToList();

projectType = filteredResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 22).Answer;
additionalCriteria = filteredResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 27).Answer;
tamidStudent = filteredResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 28).Answer;
studentEmail = filteredResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 2134).Answer;
jobDesc = filteredResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 17).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList();
experience = filteredResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 21).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList();
VCF = filteredResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 4239).Select(x => x.AnswerCode).ToList();
lang = filteredResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 23).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList();
codingLang = filteredResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 24).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList();
academic = filteredResponses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == 25).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList();
HPD = filteredResponses.FirstOrDefault(y => y.QuestionID == 26).Answer;
```

You will see that although more data is fetched this way from the table, doing it all at once instead of in 10 separate queries saves much time.

Comment: I tried both ways but it still takes too much time to fetch data even though in linqpad it throws outofmemory exception

Comment: @EngrUmair could you provide performance numbers? For each line before and after my optimization would be best

Answer (score 0):

We can use asSplitQuery() method for performance

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).